# CM7 Dialer Problems

Tags: cyanogenmod, phone-app

I am currently running CM7 on an HTC Desire HD. When I make a call, CM7's dialer for some reason has the **hold** button right where the side of my face touches the phone. I have tried to use tasker to make the screen lock and have a timeout of one second when I answer the phone or call someone, but this didn't work.

Is there a way to fix this or are there custom dialers out there that changes the look of this screen??

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not really CM7's fault. It sounds like you have an issue with the proximity sensor on the device. The screen should go black when you put the phone up to your ear. Searching, I have found that this seems to be a common problem with the Desire HD. You could try some things like [recalibrating the sensor](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/proximity-sensor-re-calibrator-for-desire-hd/).